# How to use OR in IF statement equivalents

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x

What has always bothered my when programming is the fact that no language I've programmed in supports a flexible `or` operator.

Take this piece of code written in the-standard-coding-syntax:

```
if(variable == (value1 or value2 or value3)) { ... }
```

This, of course, does not work and in order to get the desired outcome you would have to do something like this:

```
if(
  variable = value1 or
  variable = value2 or
  variable = value3
) { ... }
```

Which, in my opinion, is inefficient (or just plain ugly).

My question: Is possible to make snippet one work without being as inefficient as snippet two?

(This currently pertaining to Python)

Comment: That's not "the-standard-coding-syntax", and option 2 doesn't have any efficiency problems.

Comment: It is the most common syntax I've in countered in the languages I know (PHP, Javascript, C++, etc.).

Comment: Oh, by the way, [Perl 6 actually has the feature you want](http://doc.perl6.org/type/Junction). Supposedly Perl 6 is getting a 1.0 release around Christmas, so that'll be nice.

Answer (score 4):

This is where you would use `any`.

```
if any(variable==value for value in (value1, value2, value3)):
```

You could also use `in` for this simple of an example.

```
if variable in (value1, value2, value3):
```

If this is a question of efficiency, `in` is much faster as you can see from this disassembly.

```
dis.dis('1 in (2, 3, 4, 1)')
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               0 (1)
              3 LOAD_CONST               4 ((2, 3, 4, 1))
              6 COMPARE_OP               6 (in)
              9 RETURN_VALUE

dis.dis('any(1==x for x in (2, 3, 4, 1))')
  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (any)
              3 LOAD_CONST               0 (<code object <genexpr> at 0x036C5200, file "<dis>", line 1>)
              6 LOAD_CONST               1 ('<genexpr>')
              9 MAKE_FUNCTION            0
             12 LOAD_CONST               6 ((2, 3, 4, 1))
             15 GET_ITER
             16 CALL_FUNCTION            1 (1 positional, 0 keyword pair)
             19 CALL_FUNCTION            1 (1 positional, 0 keyword pair)
             22 RETURN_VALUE
```

So, `in` is great if you're just doing a simple compare of variables, but `any` allows for more flexibility, for an example of something possible with `any` that's not possible with `in` (Note: This is a bad example, but it's late on a Monday), take a look at this:

```
if any(0<x<y for y in (1, 3, 5, 6, -1))
```

Comment: This is not working for me. My code: `if x[len(x)-1][-1:] in (".","?","!"): x[len(x)-1] += "."` where `x` equals the user input string.

Comment: What is `x`? The results of `input()`? If so, that's a different question. It also won't work.

Comment: Yes. `x` is the result of `input()`.

Comment: I don't know what you're doing with the indexing there, because you're trying to index into a character, but it works for me. Also, this should just be `endswith()`. In the future, please ask your actual question.

Comment: @Krii: That code makes no sense. `x[len(x)-1][-1:]` is a really weird way to write `x[-1]`, and `x[len(x)-1] += anything` won't work if `x` is a string. You probably want `x += '.'`.

Comment: `x` is an array of parsed words. `x[len(x)-1]` is the last word, `[-1:]` is the last character.

Comment: So it's not the results of `input()` at all. This is why you need to ask your actual question.

Comment: I'll do that then. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Krii You need to ask a new question. Your new question is very different from this posted question.

Comment: That last example is problematic because you can ask  `if x+1 in (1,3,5,6)`. A better example would be `if any( y>x for y in (1,3,5,6) )`, though that's still easier to express as `if max([1,3,5,6]) > x`

Comment: @ChadS. Yeah, it's not the best example, but I couldn't come up with something better.

Comment: FWIW, for newer Pythons a set is better (`if variable in {value1, value2, value3}`).